# webapp version 2.4 to 2.5 out of memory

Tags: servlets, ejb, ejb-3.0, web.xml, out-of-memory

I have a requirement to update the EJB version of an application which has a schema version of 2.4, the ejb version being upgraded to is 3.0 which uses annotations, in order for the annotations to be read I need to upgrade the web app version to 2.5. When I do that and go to redeploy the app I see a out of memory error.

Can anyone push me in the right direction as to what is happening here?

00000034 annotations   I ArchiveInputStreamData mapData Collision on [ .class ] in [ Demo.war ]
00000034 annotations   I ArchiveInputStreamData mapData Collision on [ .class ] in [ Demo.war ]
00000034 annotations   I ArchiveInputStreamData mapData Collision on [ .class ] in [ Demo2.war ]

I can't put the whole thread due to privacy, its running on Was 8.0.0.2 and java 6, really after that snippet about I see lots of

- Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError"

Which suggests and out of memory now I had the webapp version of 2.4 previously all I did was change the header to

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

thanks,

Stefan

Comment: Please show the exception (error) stacktrace.

Comment: edited - I could not add the full stack trace but I can provide information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right header. I don't see `version=2.5` line in your dump.

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Beside this, in absence of error trace, I can guess that your `web.xml` may not be in order according to **new schema rules**.

You can still post the error trace. Just remove the classes so that privacy can be maintained. It only becomes guessing games when full or important part of error trace is not present.

Comment: are there great differences between schema versions, I didn't change anything within the web.xml apart from the header so maybe that could be the reason?

Comment: The best way to check this is to open your `web.xml` in eclipse or any other java editors which supports schema validation. This will show error / warnings if there is any.

Comment: thanks for the help - ah it seems we want to maintain some of the ejb2.1 bindings, Opening another question though as im having trouble with it

Comment: No worries, open new Question !