# Does the version attribute in web-app in the web descriptor affect the actual Servlet API version used?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, opencms

There are many hints through the web suggesting that the version in `web.xml`, `<web-app version="xxx">` must match the current API used (and expected) by the corresponding application. E.g.:

- [Java web app - What determines my Servlet API version? Does it get specified in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146247/413020)
- [What exactly is the web-app version? What does it affect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15985378/413020)
- [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function test must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020121/413020)
- [How can I check what version of EL is server using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237216/413020)
- [webapp version 2.4 to 2.5 out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738022/413020)

But I have failed to prove it. Does this `version` has any effect when compiling the JSPs?

---

### Background

I've been debugging a `[...] JasperException: somewhere.jsp(69,10) The function concat must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified` in a Tomcat 6.0.45.

After some research, I found that the `somewhere.jsp` invokes a bean method with arguments, something only support in EL 2.2+ (see for example [Differences between EL 2.1 and 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209200/413020)). So far so good: Tomcat 6.0.45 is a servlet 2.5 container that only supports EL 2.1.

But I then installed the same app on a Tomcat 8.0.32 (Servlet 3.1, EL 3.0), and with the same `web.xml`, the failure doesn't display, something that surprises me, because in the `web.xml`, I have `version="2.4"`.

I have also failed with further attempts to tweak the Servlet API version used to compile and run the JSPs by only changing this `version` attribute, so I'm quite puzzled.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm realizing that I've done the tests on an [OpenCms](http://www.opencms.org/en/download/opencms.html) server. Could the JSP compiler be overriden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version specified in web.xml only determines the rules that are used to parse the web.xml file. The behaviour of the container is always determined by the version of the specifications it implements.

For example, you can't disable annotation scanning (introduced in Servlet 3.0 / Tomcat 7) by specifying `version="2.5"` in the web.xml. See section 1.6.2 of the Servlet 3.0 servlet specification for an example of this requirement.

Comment: Thanks. That was my expectation before I read posts with statements like "_However, if the `web.xml` of your webapp is declared conform for example Servlet 2.4, then your webapp will run in Servlet 2.4 modus with JSP/EL 2.0._" (from [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237216/413020) that suggest the contrary. I have to say that I couldn't find anything supporting such statements in Tomcat's documentation. If no one can refute your post, I'll accept your answer and move on.